# Type error when mapping over FirebaseListObservable<any[]>

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm grabbing a collection from Firebase and trying to map over the collection, returning object instances.  My code looks like this:

```
class Todo {
  constructor(public text: string) { }
}

this.db.list('todos').map(todo => {
  return new Todo(todo);
});
```

This actually works, but I get a TypeScript intellisense error on the `new Todo(todo)` line that reads:

```
Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

I can see that `this.db.list` returns a type of `FirebaseListObservable<any[]>`. However, when I debug this line and get the type of `todo` it reports it is a string and not an array of any type.

I'm not quite sure how to go about making TypeScript happy here.

### Update

This turned out to be an error on my end.  I had incorrectly mocked out the observable response from Firebase in a test, and was looking at the results in the wrong way.  Cartant's answer helped me to see this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The observable returned by `list` will emit an array of todos; not a single todo. That is, it will emit `any[]` and each element in the emitted array will correspond to a key under `todos`.

If the keys under `todos` have string values, AngularFire2 should emit an array of wrapped values, something like this:

```
[{
  $value: '<value1>',
  $key: '<key1>'
}, {
  $value: '<value2>',
  $key: '<key2>'
}]
```

You probably want to use `Array.prototype.map` to return an array of todos:

```
this.db
  .list('todos')
  .map((todos: any[]) => todos.map((todo: any) => new Todo(todo.$value));
```

Comment: This is confusing to me, though.  If I `console.log` the `todo` inside the first map (`todos` in your example), I get a single value.  So, if my first todo in the observable array is "get milk", this is what gets outputted here.  And, if I `console.log` the `typeof` for this value, I get "string".

Comment: Fixed an error in the answer. However, what you are describing doesn't make any sense. If the value emitted by the observable is not an array, you should include your data in your question and should also include the version of AngularFire2 that you are using. If I create a `list` that references a key containing a string value, I see an empty array emitted not a string. And if the key contains child keys, `list` behaves as documented. (BTW, I am still using 2.0.0-beta.5.)

Comment: Okay, thanks, Cartant.  This turned out to be an error on my end.  What you're saying is correct.  Thank you for responding.  This helped me solve the problem.